# Order by clause with union in SQL select query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, union

Is there a way to order the union of two select all statements based on table column values.
My sample code is:

```
SELECT *  FROM emp WHERE mgr='7839' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM emp  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM emp WHERE mgr='7839') 
AND empno='7839' 
order by ename;
```

This code is showing error as:invalid identifier 'ENAME'. 
I am not using specific columns in select statement instead of * since there are more than 10 columns in the table and the code looks so big.
But ename is a column in emp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will you consider small change in your query.

```
SELECT *  FROM 
(SELECT *  FROM emp WHERE mgr='7839' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM emp  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM emp WHERE mgr='7839') 
AND empno='7839') AA 
order by AA.ename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would use use `union` for this?  Just do:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM emp e
WHERE e.mgr = '7839' OR
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM emp e2 WHERE e2.mgr = '7839') AND
       empno = '7839' 
      )
ORDER BY ename;
```